# Moving cursor from Python does not control camera of Unity

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, pyautogui

I am trying to rotate the camera (of a first person character) in Unity, by using the command: `pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration)` from the `pyautogui` library. The game does work whenever I change the position (by myself), but not when doing that command.

Unity seems to be ignoring the command (eventhough the mouse cursor moves).

What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The windows focus maybe? If you run the script after the game it may lose the focus

Comment: @Netwave hi! That is what I thought as well, so I tried to click inside the window before changing the position, and it still seems that the move movement is ignored by Unity. Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: The question is how do you start you script / change the position than? Maybe Unity just lost focus again?